# Avery DesignPro in Ubuntu

Tags: wine

Does Avery DesignPro work in Ubuntu through Wine?  If so how do I launch the program?  How about Avery Wizard for Microsoft Office in LibreOffice?

Answer (score 2):

I use Avery Design pro a lot, but its has been giving me problems using wine.  Lockup, crashes, and other things.  I found gLables, and for me and what I do is doing OK, so go ahead, and try gLables.

> gLabels is a lightweight program for creating labels, barcodes,
>   business cards and media covers for the GNOME desktop environment. It
>   is designed to work with various laser/ink-jet peel-off label and
>   business card sheets that you'll find at most office supply stores.
>
> gLabels also supports mail merge from sources such as CSV files,
>   vCards and Evolution data servers.

To [**Install gLables** [image: Install comixcursors-lefthanded]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/glabels/)

Now I have downloaded multiple templates from Avery's site, and have been working with them using Libreoffice Writer, with no problems.  So you can use the templates.  See image below.

[image]

Comment: Great!  I've downloaded the template that I need to LibreOffice and it works great!  Even selects the 4X6 tray on my printer!Can you add templates to glables.  The program looks great but it does not have the 2225 template that I use for mailing labels.  This is the template that I downloaded to LibreOffice and SUCCESS!  Thanks a million!